# Python subprocess passing multiple arguments not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have  a bash file and **passing values like this**

```py
param1="EAST US"
param2="WEST US"
param3="NORT US"

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['bash', '-c', '. /root/kickstart_test.sh;'
                   ' myfun ' + param1 + ' ' + param2 + ' ' + param3]
```

**and In my bash file I am getting these values like this**

```sh
myfun()
{
  echo $1  # output is  EAST
  echo $2  # output is  US
  echo $3  # output is  WEST
}
```

here function giving values not correct just considering **"EAST US"**   2 parameters . how I can fix this ?

Comment: Quote `param1` with `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The passed parameters need quoting and so:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
['bash', '-c', '. /root/kickstart_test.sh;'
               ' myfun "' + param1 + '" "' + param2 + '" "' + param3 + '"']
```

Comment: got it sir , and the way I am passing parameters are good ? or its not good way to do like with + sign ?

Comment: It's fine. It's just the way bash works. Without the parameters being quoted, each word will be seen as a separate parameter.